# Are there any translation check tools?

Tags: editing, software, tools, translation

Are there any tools/programs that I can use when I translate a book into another language?  I.e. I do not want to turn "wrathful grapes""into "angry raisins".

Answer (score 5):

No. All a translator has is their proficiency in both source and target language. If you don't have that, don't translate.

Comment: I am confident that my proficiency would be adequate, but the target language is Afrikaans (from South Africa) that is not well known. When I use commonly found translator tools on the internet to check words or phrases, to make sure I did not change the meaning, it often gives me poor results.  I was hoping that someone may know of a good quality program (even if not freely available on the internet)